# Upgrade from Laravel 5.3 to Laravel 5.4 and empty field converts to NULL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I have upgraded Laravel from the 5.3 to the 5.4 version, however, if I have an empty value in a text input when I submit the form I have now a NULL value instead of an empty one, and this did not happen with the 5.3 version.

I have now to forcely set a nullable or required validation rules, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 5.4, two new middlewares were included `TrimStrings` and `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull`.

In effect, for every form request, Laravel will automatically trim any white space, while also converting all empty request fields to null.

If you want to disable these then simply comment both in your `app/Http/Kernel.php`.

```php
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    // \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    // \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.4, there is a middleware `TrimStrings` which trims all empty values.

You could disable it from `app/Http/Kernel.php`.

Just remove `\App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,` from the middleware array.